# How to downgrade PHP from 7.2 to 7.0

Tags: http, centos7, php7, downgrade

I am running CentOS 7.4 and HTTP 2.4.6

I installed PHP 7.2.3

I know need to downgrade to 7.0 (reason is software company initially told me to install latest/stable for PHP and now they tell me 7.2 won't work I need 7.0 -- ugh)

How do I go from 7.2 to 7.0 in PHP?

`php -v` returns:
PHP 7.2.3 (cli) (built: Mar  2 2018 12:41:10) ( NTS )

Comment: Show the output of ˋyum list installed | grep phpˋ. And where did you get those ˋuˋ package names from like ˋphp72uˋ? Also, how did you install v7.2?

Comment: Find the package name providing the php command:  rpm -qf $(which php)

Comment: BTW, apparently you have added the repositories for EL 6 onto EL 7. This can't work.

Answer (score 6):

You have php installed from remi-php72, and you want php from remi-php70

Try:

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php72
```

Then downgrade everything and upgrade again (for noarch package)

```
yum downgrade php\*
yum update
```

Or simply (only the 7.2.3 packages)

```
yum downgrade php-bcmath php-cli php-common php-devel \
  php-gd php-gmp php-imap php-intl php-json php-ldap \
  php-mbstring php-mysqlnd php-odbc  php-pdo php-process \
  php-recode php-soap php-tidy php-xml
```

Or to remove everything and start new installation

```
yum remove php\*
```

Comment: yum remove php-common

Comment: I wouldn't try to yum downgrade and yum upgrade. That would probably not work. I'd just use `yum distro-sync` instead.

Comment: Ah, indeed, I always forget about distro-sync.... very good idea